# How and where do I set the MAXRECURSION option?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that exhausts the default `MAXRECURSION` limit of 100. Giving me the following error message:

> The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

I have found out that I need to raise the limit for this CTE using `OPTION (MAXRECURSION xxx)` but I don't know where to put this.

So far I've tried to put it next to where I define the CTE but it isn't working.  I've also tried a few different places and it's not working either.  The error I get each time is:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'.

So where should I put the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION XXX)` command in my SQL?

```
with
    tab (id,start,en) AS (
                  SELECT 1, 100, 200
        UNION ALL SELECT 2, 200, 500
    ),
    cte (id,start,en) AS (
        SELECT id, start, en FROM tab
        UNION ALL
        SELECT id, start+1, en FROM cte WHERE start+1 <= en
    )
SELECT id, start
FROM cte
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Gabe: If you run the query above, you will get recursive max 100 because the range is between 200-500. It works nicely if you remove this select. So the only option is too use OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000) but everytime I put this statement next to thing I thought is going to it's complaining that: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OPTION'. I've revised the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
with tab AS 
(
    select 1 as id, 100 as start, 200 as en
    union all
    select 2, 200, 500),
    cte AS
    (
        select id,start,en from tab
        union all
        select id,start+1 , en from cte where start+1<=en
    )

SELECT id,start from cte
order by id
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Comment: Didn't realise that I need to put under the last select statement. :) I was trying to put inside the CTE or TAB section. Thanks