# MS SQL Set Group ID Without Looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

I would like create a query in MS-SQL to make a column containing an incrementing group number.

This is how I want my data to return:

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3
------------------------------
    I    |     1    |     1
    O    |     2    |     2
    O    |     2    |     3
    I    |     3    |     4
    O    |     4    |     5
    O    |     4    |     6
    O    |     4    |     7
    O    |     4    |     8
    I    |     5    |     9
    O    |     6    |    10
```

- `Column 1` is the `I` and `O` meaning In and Out.
- `Column 2` is the row Group (this should increment when `Column 1` changes).
- `Column 3` is the Row-number.

So how can I write my query so that `Column 2` increments every time `Column 1` changes?

Comment: Do you have any other column to find the order

Comment: your question makes no sense

Comment: Anything tried so far?

Comment: I tried looping, it works but it takes 30 minutes for 30K records

Comment: why do you remove the formatting again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to perform this kind of operation you need some column that can identify the order of the rows. If you have a column that determines this order, an identity column for example, it can be used to do something like this:

**Runnable sample:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Groups
    (
      id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) , -- added identity to provide order
      Column1 VARCHAR(1)
    )

INSERT  INTO #Groups
        ( Column1 )
VALUES  ( 'I' ),
        ( 'O' ),
        ( 'O' ),
        ( 'I' ),
        ( 'O' ),
        ( 'O' ),
        ( 'O' ),
        ( 'O' ),
        ( 'I' ),
        ( 'O' );

;
WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   id ,
                        Column1 ,
                        1 AS Column2
               FROM     #Groups
               WHERE    id = 1
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   g.id ,
                        g.Column1 ,
                        CASE WHEN g.Column1 = cte.Column1 THEN cte.Column2
                             ELSE cte.Column2 + 1
                        END AS Column2
               FROM     #Groups g
                        INNER JOIN cte ON cte.id + 1 = g.id
             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    cte
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- required to allow for more than 100 recursions

DROP TABLE #Groups
```

This code effectively loops through the records, comparing each row to the next and incrementing the  value of `Column2` if the value in `Column1` changes.

If you don't have an identity column, then you might consider adding one.

**Credit @AeroX:**

With 30K records, the last line: `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)` is required to override the default of 100 recursions when using a [Common Table Expression (CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx). Setting it to `0`, means that it isn't limited.

Comment: With the OP having 30k rows they would need to set the [`MAXRECURSION`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3349322/2594742) level higher if using this method

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you have sqlserver 2012+

```
DECLARE @t table(col1 char(1), col3 int identity(1,1))

INSERT @t values
('I'), ('O'), ('O'), ('I'), ('O'), ('O'), ('O'), ('O'), ('I'), ('O')

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    case when lag(col1) over (order by col3) = col1 
         then 0 else 1 end increase, 
    col1,
    col3
  FROM @t
)
SELECT
  col1,
  sum(increase) over (order by col3) col2,
  col3
FROM CTE
```

Result:

```
col1  col2  col3
I     1     1
O     2     2
O     2     3
I     3     4
O     4     5
O     4     6
O     4     7
O     4     8
I     5     9
O     6     10
```