# Getting errors for a recursive SQL CTE query

Tags: sql, recursive-query

I'm using the following query in postgresql to generate a list of consecutive dates using CTE and running into two issues:

1. If I run the query as below, I get a syntax error related to the last line (OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0))
2. If I remove this last line, I get the error "There is a WITH item named "datecalendar", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query. HINT:  Use WITH RECURSIVE, or re-order the WITH items to remove forward references."

```
WITH datecalendar
     AS (SELECT cast ('2023-08-08' as date) AS thedate
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd (day, 1, datecalendar.thedate) AS thedate
         FROM   datecalendar
         WHERE  Dateadd (day, 1, datecalendar.thedate) <= cast ('2023-08-12' as date))
SELECT * FROM datecalendar
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Can someone please suggest how I can get around both issues above? I've done a fair amount of searching for solutions. For '1', the suggestion has been to ensure that OPTION ... is placed at the right point in the statement (e.g. [How and where do I set the MAXRECURSION option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349322/how-and-where-do-i-set-the-maxrecursion-option))  which I do seem to be doing.

For '2', I haven't been able to find a comparable solution.

Comment: Which DBMS and version are you using?

Comment: Looks like you are using SQL Server syntax in a different RDBMS than SQL Server - Error message looks like Postgresql

Comment: So you probably want to be looking at `generate_series` instead of that anyway

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, using postgresql. I updated the description accordingly

Comment: Is this is solution https://sqlize.online/s/9R ?

Comment: As Martin mentioned, use generate_series instead of CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) to generate a series of dates in PostgreSQL, but you're mixing syntax that's typical for Microsoft SQL Server. Let's address each of your problems:

1. **OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0):** This line is specific to SQL Server. PostgreSQL doesn't have this option. Instead, if you need to limit the recursion, you would do that within the recursive query itself, like how you're doing with the **'WHERE'** clause.
2. **WITH item named "datecalendar":** The error you're seeing is because you need to specify the **'WITH RECURSIVE'** keyword when using recursive CTEs in PostgreSQL.

Let's re-write your query to work with PostgreSQL:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE datecalendar AS (
    SELECT cast('2023-08-08' as date) AS thedate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT thedate + interval '1 day'
    FROM datecalendar
    WHERE thedate + interval '1 day' <= cast('2023-08-12' as date)
)
SELECT * FROM datecalendar;
```

Key Changes:

- Replaced **WITH** with WITH **RECURSIVE**.
- Utilized PostgreSQL's date arithmetic **('thedate + interval '1 day'')** instead of SQL Server's DateAdd() function.
- Removed the **OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)**  line since it's not applicable to PostgreSQL.

Running the above query in a PostgreSQL database will give you the desired series of dates.

Comment: I had to modify the query to the following to get around some errors from your posted query, but not able to make it work - not getting an output (runs for 2+ min). thoughts?


WITH RECURSIVE datecalendar AS (
    SELECT cast('2023-08-08' as date) AS thedate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cast ('2023-08-08' as date) + 1
    FROM datecalendar
    WHERE cast ('2023-08-08' as date) + 1 <= cast ('2023-08-09' as date)
 )
SELECT * FROM datecalendar

Comment: It seems like there's a small mistake in your recursive query. The issue with your modified query is that you are always selecting and adding to the same starting date ('2023-08-08'), which means it will run indefinitely without ever reaching the end condition.

Here's the corrected version:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE datecalendar AS (
    SELECT cast('2023-08-08' as date) AS thedate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT thedate + 1
    FROM datecalendar
    WHERE thedate + 1 <= cast('2023-08-12' as date)
)
SELECT * FROM datecalendar;

```

Comment: Key changes:

In the recursive part of the query, we are now adding to thedate rather than the constant '2023-08-08'.

PostgreSQL allows simple arithmetic with dates. So, thedate + 1 will add one day to the date, without needing to cast or use intervals.

The given query should output:

yaml
2023-08-08
2023-08-09
2023-08-10
2023-08-11
2023-08-12
If you want to generate dates only up to '2023-08-09', then you can modify the WHERE condition in the recursive query accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much @Fatih - that worked. Appreciate the help!